# Calling a Google Cloud Function from within Python

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, python-requests, google-cloud-functions

I'm trying to call a Google Cloud function **from within Python** using the following:

```
import requests
url = "MY_CLOUD_FUNCTON_URL"
data = {'name': 'example'}
response = requests.post(url, data = data)
```

but I get back the error: `Your client does not have permission to get URL MY_CLOUD_FUNCTON from this server`

Does anyone know how I can avoid this error? I am assuming I should be passing credentials as part of the request somehow?

Also note that if I instead try to call the function via gcloud from the command line like the below then it works, but i want to do this from within python

```
gcloud functions call MY_CLOUD_FUNCTON --data '{"name": "example"}'
```

Any help would be really appreciated!

Answer (score 11):

Given a working Cloud Function in **HTTP** mode which requires authentication in order to be triggered.

You need to generate an authentication token and insert it in the header as shown below:

```
import os
import json
import requests
import google.oauth2.id_token
import google.auth.transport.requests

os.environ['GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS'] = './my-service-account.json'
request = google.auth.transport.requests.Request()
audience = 'https://mylocation-myprojectname.cloudfunctions.net/MyFunctionName'
TOKEN = google.oauth2.id_token.fetch_id_token(request, audience)

r = requests.post(
    audience, 
    headers={'Authorization': f"Bearer {TOKEN}", "Content-Type": "application/json"},
    data=json.dumps({"key": "value"})  # possible request parameters
)
r.status_code, r.reason
```

Answer (score 4):

You have a few options here. Either open the function to the public so that anyone can call it or take the more secure route, albeit necessitating a bit more steps. I will cover the 2nd option since it's the one I would suggest for security reasons, but should you be satisfied with simply opening the function to the public ( which is especially useful if you are trying to create a public endpoint after all ), see this [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/securing/managing-access-iam#allowing_unauthenticated_function_invocation).

If you want to limit who can invoke your GCF however, you would have to perform a few more steps.

1. [Create a service account](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/creating-managing-service-accounts#creating) and give it the Cloud Functions Invoker role ( if you simply want to restrict it's permissions to only invoke the GCF )
2. After you assign the Service Account a role(s), the next page will give you the option to [create a key](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/creating-managing-service-account-keys#creating_service_account_keys)
3. After creating the Service Account Key and downloading it as `credentials.json`, the next step is straightforward. You would simply [populate the environment variable](https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/production#providing_credentials_to_your_application) `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS` with the path to the `credentials.json` file.

Once these steps are done, you can simply invoke the GCF as you did before, only this time, it will invoke it **as** the service account that you created, which contained all the permissions necessary to invoke a GCF.

Comment: Google doesn't recommend doing it this way, though, because then you have your key lying around. "Service account keys could pose a security risk if compromised. We recommend you avoid downloading service account keys and instead use the Workload Identity Federation."

Answer (score 0):

This may be obvious to many, but to add to Marco's answer (I can't comment yet):

Make sure to install the `google-auth` package, **not** the `google` package. More details [in the documentation](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/securing/authenticating) and [the requirements.txt](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/python-docs-samples/blob/912ccc31e1caf94569c2b92aa04bf5e136e08fcf/auth/service-to-service/requirements.txt) for the code on GitHub.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).